# How to quickly duplicate and increase number?

Tags: flutter, dart

I need to load 365 days data, I search a quick solution to not have to do manualy 365 modification

I see in android studio  ctrl + R and regex but not found how to do.

here is an example

```
 var daysfromnow1 = now.add(new Duration(days: 0));
    var daysfromnow2 = now.add(new Duration(days: -1));
    var daysfromnow3 = now.add(new Duration(days: -2));
    var daysfromnow4 = now.add(new Duration(days: -3));
    var daysfromnow5 = now.add(new Duration(days: -4));
    var daysfromnow6 = now.add(new Duration(days: -5));
    var daysfromnow7 = now.add(new Duration(days: -6));
    var daysfromnow8 = now.add(new Duration(days: -7));
    var daysfromnow9 = now.add(new Duration(days: -8));
    var daysfromnow10 = now.add(new Duration(days: -9));
....
   var daysfromnow365 = now.add(new Duration(days: -364));
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all you should store your variables in a `List`. Accessing `daysfromnow10` could be done with `list[9]`.

This is how you can populate your List :

```dart
final today = DateTime.now();
List<Duration> week = [for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) today.add(Duration(days: -i))];
List<Duration> year = [for (int i = 0; i < 365; i++) today.add(Duration(days: -i))];
```

Comment: It's too late I think :( I publish my app like this if I change,  old user will no longer have their data. Solution can be a scan that transfert all my saved key in the list but don't know how to do ^^